# How to display postgres database information in htmlpage using php?

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have made a connection to `Postgres` database using `PHP`, to display information in a webpage, but getting nothing on my `HTML` page, how to check that connection is being made to my `Postgres` database using `PHP` to get the tables displayed in a webpage?

Here is the code-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            $db_connection = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=1234");
        ?>
        <?php
            $temparray = array();
            $result = pg_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM test1");
            if (!$result) {
                echo "An error occurred.\n";
                exit;
            }

            while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) 
            {
                array_push($temparray, $row); //save your data into array
            }

            echo json_encode($temparray);

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe add a log that the connection is successful, and then be sure that your request give some results. otherwise having a blank page is normal.

Comment: how can we do that, can you help me? How can we display this temparray data in my web page?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.examples-basic.php) is an example from the official PHP docs. I suggest you to add the following line to determine if the connection to the database was successful:

```
$db_connnection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres 
          password=1234") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
```